# Spinner Itemselected Listner not triggring while using Custom Adpater(Data from api Json)

Tags: android, json, spinner, android-spinner

I stuck with spinner it working fine if am passing entries list but when I pass data to custom adapter  (fetched from Api) in Json my first selected item is not showing in spinner but I can see my list on drop down menu and on any item selection itemSelectedListner doesn't Triggers. I already dig stack overflow but wasn't able to find any helpful answer. here my code goes.

**custom adapter**

```
    package com.evantagesoft.warehouse.management.sys.adapter;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint; import android.app.Activity; 
    import android.content.Context; import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
    import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; 
    import  android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.evantagesoft.warehouse.management.sys.R; 
    import com.evantagesoft.warehouse.management.sys.model.entities.uomAPIs.UoM_List;
    import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
    import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;


           public class CustomSpinnerAdapter_UoM extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
    private Context context;

    private ArrayList<? extends Object> arrayList;
    private String tag;


    public CustomSpinnerAdapter_UoM(Activity context, int resourceId, int textView, String tag , ArrayList<? extends Object> arrayList) {
            super(context, resourceId, textView, (List<Object>) arrayList);
            this.context = context;
            this.tag = tag;
            this.arrayList = arrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_acc_link_open_view, null);
            }
            /*LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_view_w, null);
         */
            Object item =  getItem(position);
            TextView mBankNameTv;
            mBankNameTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_bank_name);
            assert item != null;
            mBankNameTv.setText(((UoM_List) item).getName());
            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_acc_link_open_view, null);

            }
            Object item = getItem(position);

            TextView mBankNameTv;
            mBankNameTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_bank_name);

            //mBankNameTv.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAppWhite));

            assert item != null;
            mBankNameTv.setText(((UoM_List) item).getName());

            return convertView;
    } }
```

**here i am setting my adapter to spinner in view holder**

```
    CustomSpinnerAdapter_UoM spinnerAdapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter_UoM((Activity) context, R.layout.spinner_item_acc_link_open_view, R.id.tv_bank_name, PACKAGING_TYPES,presenter.getUoM_List(1));
    mPack_sp.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    CustomSpinnerAdapter_UoM spinnerAdapter1 = new CustomSpinnerAdapter_UoM((Activity) context,  R.layout.spinner_item_acc_link_open_view, R.id.tv_bank_name, UNIT_OF_MASS,presenter.getUoM_List(3));
    mU_Mass_sp.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter1);
    CustomSpinnerAdapter_UoM spinnerAdapter2 = new CustomSpinnerAdapter_UoM((Activity) context,  R.layout.spinner_item_acc_link_open_view, R.id.tv_bank_name, UNIT_OF_DISTANCE,presenter.getUoM_List(2));
    mU_Dist_sp.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter2);
```

**here selected listners**

```
    mPack_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //if(mPack_sp.getSelectedItemPosition()!=0)
            presenter.spinnerItemSelected("packType", ((UoM_List)mPack_sp.getSelectedItem()).getCode(),getAdapterPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    mU_Mass_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //if(mU_Mass_sp.getSelectedItemPosition()!=0)
            presenter.spinnerItemSelected("weightUOM",((UoM_List)mU_Mass_sp.getSelectedItem()).getCode(),getAdapterPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
    mU_Dist_sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //if(mU_Dist_sp.getSelectedItemPosition()!=0)
            presenter.spinnerItemSelected("dimensionUOM",((UoM_List)mU_Dist_sp.getSelectedItem()).getCode(),getAdapterPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

**Here the Model class**

```
package com.evantagesoft.warehouse.management.sys.model.entities.uomAPIs;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class UoM_List implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("code")
    private String code;

    @SerializedName("height")
    private int height;

    @SerializedName("isActive")
    private boolean isActive;

    @SerializedName("isDimension")
    private boolean isDimension;

    @SerializedName("isPacking")
    private boolean isPacking;

    @SerializedName("isUnit")
    private boolean isUnit;

    @SerializedName("isWeight")
    private boolean isWeight;

    @SerializedName("length")
    private int length;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("packingMaxWeight")
    private int packingMaxWeight;

    @SerializedName("sizeUom")
    private String sizeUom;

    @SerializedName("weightUom")
    private String weightUom;

    @SerializedName("width")
    private int width;

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        isActive = active;
    }

    public boolean isDimension() {
        return isDimension;
    }

    public void setDimension(boolean dimension) {
        isDimension = dimension;
    }

    public boolean isPacking() {
        return isPacking;
    }

    public void setPacking(boolean packing) {
        isPacking = packing;
    }

    public boolean isUnit() {
        return isUnit;
    }

    public void setUnit(boolean unit) {
        isUnit = unit;
    }

    public boolean isWeight() {
        return isWeight;
    }

    public void setWeight(boolean weight) {
        isWeight = weight;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPackingMaxWeight() {
        return packingMaxWeight;
    }

    public void setPackingMaxWeight(int packingMaxWeight) {
        this.packingMaxWeight = packingMaxWeight;
    }

    public String getSizeUom() {
        return sizeUom;
    }

    public void setSizeUom(String sizeUom) {
        this.sizeUom = sizeUom;
    }

    public String getWeightUom() {
        return weightUom;
    }

    public void setWeightUom(String weightUom) {
        this.weightUom = weightUom;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your data class ?

Comment: Adapter looks good. And it works as expected. Have you checked list returned by presenter.getUoM_List(1) ? Does it return valid list ? 3 spinners are inside view holder of recycler view ?

Comment: oh my bad I was setting my spinner adapter before my api response.. just had to set spinner adapter after api response....